# Clothing doesn't clip in viewport, but clips through skin on final render

Tags: rendering, animation, physics, cloth-simulation, clipping

*The Relevant Blend File:*  [image]

I have a character model with tight clothing. I have transferred the weights from the base skin mesh to the clothing, and have also parented the clothing and base mesh to an armature, and have made a basic walking animation.

The armature uses bendy bones for the jiggle physics of her breasts. However, I'm not satisfied by the effect, and so in addition to that, have added two mesh deforming objects around the breasts and clothing, and attached a clothing modifier to the two objects for more complex physics:

[image]

I thought that this worked well, as when I ran the simulation in the viewport, any sort of clipping issues were well within acceptable levels:

[image]

However, when I went to render the animation, the end result was... really bad:

[image]

If I had gotten the same issue in both the render and the viewport, then I would think that my original strategy is just flat out wrong. However, the fact that the viewport shows good results makes me think that I'm on the right track, but that maybe just some settings need to be tweaked somewhere to get the proper results.

I don't really know where to look, however. I tried increasing the quality steps for the cloth simulation, but that resulted in only marginal improvement. Does anyone have any ideas for why the render doesn't match the viewport?

Comment: I would look first for any subdivision modifiers, and make sure that their render iterations were the same as preview iterations.

Comment: @Nathan, Sadly, I don't have any active subdivision modifiers at all on any of the meshes. :(

Comment: Then people are probably going to need a file to have any hope of helping you.

Comment: @Nathan is that allowed? I'd be willing to send a file if necessary.

Comment: Yes, even encouraged.  https://blend-exchange.com/ is preferred.

Comment: I have uploaded the relevant blend file, @Nathan. If you could have a look and figure out what's going on, I'd be very grateful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I baked the vest physics and the vest did not fall down on next render.
[image: Vest physics properties]

Comment: Huh... well, whadya know? Could someone perhaps explain why baking does this? I was under the impression that deformations due to cloth modifiers were always calculated per render, and that baking only recomputed them? Is there a reason why baking would also increase their accuracy?